# Issue with implementing UUIDs with Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, uuid, hibernate-envers

Our application is using [Hibernate envers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e4099) to provide auditing on updates to entities. Whenever an entity is modified (or inserted), a backup of the entity (i.e. the table’s row) is saved to an "AUD" table.

This provides us with auditing functionality (which is a requirement) and  has been working well up until now. But we are now facing issues because we need to migrate to using UUIDs as data keys. Our application will be run in a distributed environment with limited or intermittent internet access, so we will be using SymmetricDS to manage data synchronisation, and UUIDs will allow us to do that without causing data conflicts.

The problem we are facing with Hibernate envers is that the [RevisionNumber annotation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/RevisionNumber.java) that is used to add the REV number into the AUD table will only work with int, Integer, long and Long identifiers.

We have implemented a class called AuditRevision (that extends the Hibernate class [DefaultRevisionEntity](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/DefaultRevisionEntity.java)) with some extra attributes, and have implemented an AuditRevisionListener (that implements Hibernate’s EntityTrackingRevisionListener) to manage saving and updating the extra data. However, in order to allow us to save revisions using UUIDs instead of an auto incrementing id, we rewrote AuditRevision so that it doesn't extend DefaultRevisionEntity and instead defines its own UUID id.

We then saw the following error in our application:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The field annotated with @RevisionNumber must be of type int, Integer, long or Long
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.RevisionInfoConfiguration.searchForRevisionInfoCfgInProperties(RevisionInfoConfiguration.java:224)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.RevisionInfoConfiguration.searchForRevisionInfoCfg(RevisionInfoConfiguration.java:304)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.RevisionInfoConfiguration.configure(RevisionInfoConfiguration.java:347)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.spi.AuditConfiguration.<init>(AuditConfiguration.java:119)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.spi.AuditConfiguration.getFor(AuditConfiguration.java:180)
at org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:76)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
... 41 more
```

We are unsure how to continue. If we can't replace the long primary key of the AuditRevision table to use a UUID id, we could add a UUID (or another id or key) to the AuditRevision table and then use it along with the auto increment id as a composite key. The AUD tables will then need to reference the UUID, which we thought we could manage using a database trigger because we don't have control over the AUD tables.

Another option is that we could also rewrite the Hibernate envers library or fork their code and make the necessary modifications to support UUID.

Does anyone have any experience of this problem? How would you solve it?

We are using Hibernate 4.3.7.Final with a MySQL 5.7 database

Comment: If you want to use UUIDs for your main table primary keys, that's your choice.  There is considerable performance implications you should consider by doing that on any database platform, fair warning.  That aside, why must the Envers schema be subjected to the UUID primary key notion?  The reason the PK for Envers requires a numeric value is because queries use the fact that revisions are sequential in nature and thus some assumptions can be made and used to improve query performance between related audited entities.

Comment: Thank you for your response. We have researched the implications of using UUIDs (and have taken some mitigating precautions with respect to performance) but unfortunately we need to be able to synchronise databases that can be offline as we work in a very low resource environment). We are, however, concerned about your comment that there are Envers queries that require that revision numbers need to be sequential. Could you explain further and perhaps comment on our suggestion to add another column that could be used in combination with the revision to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: First off, the Envers Query API expects revision numbers to be sub class implementations of `Number`, so any change to support non-numeric derived revision values impact this interface and requires changes.  Secondly, will your UUIDs be solely based on time or will the local mac / machine id play an influence here too?

Comment: Would you be able to consider a distributed envers solution where node1/node2 contribute envers changes to their local db as if they were stand-alone.  Your synchronize your two nodes, a custom algorithm resorts and generates *new* audit entries into a new synced envers db that you replicate back to your node1/node2 envs?  Audit history queries always hit this replicated back env, meaning history queries are delayed until synchronized, but you avoid this complicated uuid notion and can continue to use numeric values for revisions.

Comment: I really liked the distributed envers suggestion (thanks), although it would still need to be managed in a low resource setting where there could be long (days, weeks or worse) periods of no connectivity. If we used SymmetricDS I believe we can re-write the ids and re-order using our timestamps, although I'm not sure exactly how that'd work. I liked the fact we'd manage a separate "audit" data warehouse separately from the application data, but unfortunately we don't have the time to invest in this solution now.

Comment: what does uuid haveto do with revision? why a varchar uuid makes problem for revisions?